# Computing Ext over groups derived from fields

Tags: homology-cohomology, functors

Let $F$ be a finite field of order $p^n$. Let $K$ be a degree $d$ extension of $F$. Let $F^+$ and $K^+$ denote the additive groups of $F$ and $K$, respectively. Let $F^*$ and $K^*$ denote the multiplicative groups of units of $F$ and $K,$ respectively. Compute $Ext^i_{\mathbb{Z}}(F^+, K^+)$ and $Ext^i_{\mathbb{Z}}(F^*, K^*)$ for all $i$.

I know that Abelian groups can be viewed as Z-modules and all previous Ext computations I have done involved simple Z-modules so this problem seems very out of the ordinary to me. My guess as to what the projective resolution of $F^+$ is $$\cdots Z \rightarrow Z \rightarrow (Z/pZ)^n \rightarrow 0$$

EDIT:

After applying $Hom(\_,(Z/pZ)^{nd})$, we have $$0 \rightarrow Hom((Z/pZ)^n,(Z/pZ)^{nd}) \xrightarrow{d_0} (Z/pZ)^{nd} \xrightarrow{d_1} \cdots $$

Any hints?

Comment: You just need to know that if $F$ is a finite field of order $p^n$, then $F^+$ is a $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ vector space, so this group is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^n$. For the multiplicative group, you just need to know that $F^*$ is cyclic, so this group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/(p^n-1)\mathbb{Z}$. Using this, you can easily compute the Ext groups.

Comment: I appreciate your response. Do I still consider the projective resolution?

Comment: Up to you. Either you consider a projective resolution to do the computation, or you use the well known formula which gives $\operatorname{Ext}^1(\mathbb{Z/nZ,Z/mZ})$.

Comment: Oh yes, the Ext values for $i \ge 2$ are just 0 and so $Ext^1 (F^+, K^+) = \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ while $Ext^1 (F^*, K^*) = \mathbb{Z}/(p^n-1)\mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: I disagree with the former $Ext^1(F^+,K^+)=Ext^1((\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^n,(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{nd})=(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{n^2d}$. I agree with the latter.

Comment: Do you mean $Ext^0 = Hom$? After taking $Hom$ of my projective resolution, I find that the maps of my complex alternate between isomorphism and 0 map.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57918/discussion-between-yunus-syed-and-roland).